# OpenResty with Docker Compose cannot resolve own name (hostname.domainname) in Lua block

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, openresty

I have a docker image containing an OpenResty server. I am running it within a docker-compose file like this:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  dev.example.com:
    # etc.
```

If I set the `resolver` to use the Docker one in the OpenResty configuration, then I can refer to `dev.example.com` and it resolves to the correct IP:

```
http {
  resolver 127.0.0.11;
}
```

However, I would prefer not to name the service `dev.example.com`, and instead use `hostname` and `domainname` in docker-compose:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  proxy:
    domainname: example.com
    hostname: dev
    # etc.
```

This would enable me to use environment variables to control the hostname. The problem is that when I use these parameters instead of the service name, `dev.example.com` can no longer be resolved within the Lua blocks, even though basic tests with `ping`, `curl` etc. from within the running container resolve correctly, and a simple block like this works in either case:

```
location /test {
  proxy_pass https://dev.example.com/static.html
}
```

How can I configure the domain/hostname dynamically without changing the service name, in a way that is compatible with OpenResty?

Comment: Why does the name matter inside the nginx configuration? The proxy is always proxy, no matter what extra hostname you give it. Why not just refer to it as such?

Comment: This container is being run as a proxy in an OAuth2 flow, which means that there are URLs that should work both internally and externally. For example, the "redirect URL" when a login is successful must be one that can be reached from outside of the docker environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing the `domainname` and `hostname`, the `container_name` can be specified:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  proxy:
    container_name: dev.example.com
    # etc.
```

One of the effects of setting the container name is that the Docker DNS resolves `dev.example.com` to the container.